# Where should my rspec helpers go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I would like to write a helper that will only be used in my spec files and I do not know where this code should go.

I am not trying to test an app helper and I do not feel like creating an app helper that will only be used for testing.

What is the good practice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically I put these in `spec/support/spec_helpers`. I then include those modules in the appropriate examples.

If you have some that are useful to all specs of a certain type (e.g. all request specs) then you can do

```
config.include SomeHelper, :type => :request
```

which will include that module into all your request example groups.